# How to make mocha wait before moving to the next test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, supertest

> When i ran npm test i got a 'TypeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER_VALUE]: Invalid value "undefined" for header "x-access-token"' error. Seems like mocha moves on to the second test before getting the token. I tried adding a delay with the setTimeOut method but i still got the above error.

```
 // creates valid-user object
    const validUser = {
      username: 'Rigatoni',
      email: 'yahoo.com',
      password: 'qwerty1234567',
    };
    describe('Post Tests', () => {
      // login and get token...
      let token;
      before((done) => {
        request(app)
          .post('/api/v1/auth/login')
          .send(validUser)
          .end((err, res) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-destructuring
            token = res.body.token;
            console.log('token', token);
            expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
          });
        // console.log('token test');
        done();
      });

      describe('GET all posts', () => {
        it('should return all posts', (done) => {
          request(app)
            .get('/api/v1/posts')
            .set('x-access-token', token)
            .end((err, res) => {
              expect(res.body.success).to.equal(true);
            });
          done();
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests are almost right!

The `done` callback is provided to let Mocha know when it's OK to move on. However, you are calling `done()` in your tests right *after* calling the asynchronous `request` method; Mocha thinks the test is done before you even make the request.

Move your `done()` call for each test into a callback function (for example, on the line right after your `expect()`), so that it isn't executed until after the request completes. Then Mocha will wait until the test is over before moving on.

Example:

```
request(app)
        .get('/api/v1/posts')
        .set('x-access-token', token)
        .end((err, res) => {
          expect(res.body.success).to.equal(true);
          done();
        });
```